# How can i access to transitive dependencies to update them in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

when i run pub upgrade i am getting these tips which they are out of the date but don't know where could i update them .. i even don't have them in my normal `dependencies`

[image]

could please anyone tell me what is this and how can i update them ?

i tried to update everything .. `dependencies`, `gradle` `Android studio` `flutter sdk` i all have them up to date but these still pop up when i run pup upgrade

Answer (score 16):

"Transitive dependency" means your program depends on it, because of a dependency you have that depends on it. So in other words, a package you use uses for example `async 2.8.2`. There is little you can do other than waiting for that package owner to update *their* package, so you can update that package.

To find out which of your dependencies uses which other dependency, you can run:

```
flutter pub deps
```

It will show you a dependency tree with version numbers.

Comment: It does show them, but how do you actually update them?

Comment: You saved me from running mad :). There is a Transitive a library I have wanted to remove from my application, have therefore been all along looking for its source. Today I have found its immediate dependency.

Answer (score 1):

1- If you need to update specific package of **transitive dependencies** run this command with replace **package_name** to specific package name:

`flutter pub upgrade package_name`

2- To update to the latest compatible versions **of all the dependencies** listed in the pubspec.yaml file includes **transitive dependencies** run this command:

`flutter pub upgrade`

Comment: Command "flutter pub outdated" shows packages versions of "Current, Upgradable, Resolvable, Latest". In my case it shows that the versions  "Current, Upgradable, Resolvable" are the same, but the "Latest" is higher. I tried to upgrade to the highest version using "flutter pub upgrade xml" command, but it did not upgrade, I got the message: "xml 6.1.0 (6.2.0 available)", "13 packages have newer versions incompatible with dependency constraints". Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

try this

in your `pubspace.yaml`

```yaml
dependencies:
    xml: 1.0.0
dependencies_override:
    xml: 6.2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

According to Dart,

Transitive dependencies: A dependency that your package indirectly uses because one of its dependencies requires it. If your package depends on A, which in turn depends on B which depends on C, then A is an immediate dependency and B and C are transitive ones.

A file named pubspec.lock that specifies the concrete versions and other identifying information for every immediate and transitive dependency a package relies on.

Unlike the pubspec, which only lists immediate dependencies and allows version ranges, the lock file comprehensively pins down the entire dependency graph to specific versions of packages. A lockfile ensures that you can recreate the exact configuration of packages used by an application.

The lockfile is generated automatically for you by pub when you run pub get, pub upgrade, or pub downgrade. If your package is an application package, you will typically check this into source control. For library packages, you usually won’t.

---

If you want to update your transitive dependencies, they can be found in your 'pubspec.lock' file. You can upgrade them there.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

For me I ran '**flutter** pub upgrade'
and I got this message:

"8 packages have newer versions incompatible with dependency constraints.
Try `flutter pub outdated` for more information."

so I just ran '**flutter** pub outdated' in the TERMINAL and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For my part I just replaced the versions of each package manually by the values of the last column in the pubspec.lock file and it worked.